# elementary symmetric polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to make an elementary symmetric polynomial from $[ \ (X-Y)(X-Z)(Y-Z) \ ]^2$

all I can do is this:
$ [ \ (X-Y)(X-Z)(Y-Z) \ ]^2 = [ \ X^2Y -X^2Z -XYZ +XZ^2 -XY^2 +XYZ +Y^2Z -YZ^2\ ]^2 = [\ X^2Y - X^2Z - Y^2X + Y^2Z + Z^2X - Z^2Y \ ] ^2 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Delta=[(X-Y)(X-Z)(Y-Z)]^2$ is the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of the cubic polynomial $$(T-X)(T-Y)(T-Z)=T^3+bT^2+cT+d$$ and so can be written as 
$$
\Delta = b^2c^2-4c^3-4b^3d-27d^2+18bcd
$$
where $-b=X+Y+Z$, $c=XY+YZ+ZX$, $-d=XYZ$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: See http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/ant/ch6-solns/ch6-qu15.pdf for the detailed computation.

Answer (score 1):

$((X-Y)(Y-Z)(Z-X))^2$ is symmetric and homogeneous of degree $6$, so if $E_i$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $i$, it is a linear combination of $E_1^6,E_1^4E_2,E_1^3E_3,E_1^2E_2^2, E_1E_2E_3,E_2^3,E_3^2$.

You have a few possibilities to compute this.

First you can develop the whole thing (why did you stop before developing the final square ?), then you look at the leading monomial of the expression, which will be of the form $X^{b+c+d} Y^{b+c} Z^b$, and you replace it with $E_1^dE_2^cE_3^b - (E_1^dE_2^cE_3^b - X^{b+c+d} Y^{b+c} Z^b)$ (keep the left half in terms of $E_i$ but express the right half in terms of the $X_i$). Repeat until you have turned everything into an expression in terms of the $E_i$.

One other way to do this is that you have to find $7$ coefficients, so by looking at $7$ carefully chosen values of $X,Y,Z$ you obtain a linear system to solve.
In order to obtain a system as simple as possible, you should aim to have a few triplets with some of the $E_i$ being $0$, for example $(0,0,1),(0,1,-1)$, and possibly $(1,\frac{1+\sqrt {-3}}2,\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}2)$